# Update UILabel text value , when changing the user permission for notification in application setting page?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uilabel, unnotificationrequest

In my scenario, User will get an alert for receiving Notification in application. If the user clicks on "Don't Allow" UILabel is updated with "Not enabled". If the user wants to change the notification,User will be navigated to application setting page to change the notification permission status.

```
func checkNotificationPermission(){

UNUserNotificationCenter.current().requestAuthorization(options:[.badge, .alert, .sound]){


        (granted, error) in

        if granted == true {

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("notificaation access true")
                     self.notificationAccessLbl?.text = "Enabled"         
        }
        }
        else {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.notificationAccessLbl?.text = "Not enabled" 
            }
        } 
    }
    UIApplication.shared.registerForRemoteNotifications() }
```

But when the user comes back to application, The UILabel is not getting updated when the user comes to application from Setting page.

for Updating the UILabel in application after the user comes from setting page to application. I Have Called

```
func checkNotificationPermission()
```

to update UILabel Value in  `ViewDidAppear()`  Method and I register the a function in  `applicationwillbecomeactive method()` Kindly help me in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have switch in setting page in application which allows user to enable disable push and that will be send on server but before that user must have allowed push from settings page of Device. here is my solution

I have created global object

```
var isPushEnabledFromSettings = false {
    didSet {
         // you can set label value here in main queue
    }
}
```

and one method to check it

```
func isPushPermissionGiven (permission:@escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
    if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        let current = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        current.getNotificationSettings(completionHandler: {settings in
            switch settings.authorizationStatus {
            case .notDetermined:
                permission(false)
            case .denied:
                permission(false)
            case .authorized:
                permission(true)
            }
        })
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
        if UIApplication.shared.isRegisteredForRemoteNotifications {
            permission(true)


        } else {
            permission(false)

        }
    }
}
```

and in view did load  added these lines

```
    self.isPushPermissionGiven { (permission) in
        self.isPushEnabledFromSettings = permission
    }

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil, queue: .main) {[weak self] (notificaiont) in
        guard let strongSelf = self  else {return }

        strongSelf.isPushPermissionGiven { (permission) in
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                strongSelf.isPushEnabledFromSettings = permission
            }
        }
    }
```

Now I have switch in setting page which allows user to enable disable push

```
@objc func switchChanged (sender:UISwitch) {

    guard self.isPushEnabledFromSettings else {
        AppDelegate.sharedDelegate.navigateUesrToSettings(withMessage: "Please grant push permission from settings")
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5, execute: {
            sender.setOn(false, animated: false)
        })
        return

    }
}



  func navigateUesrToSettings (withTitle title:String = "YourApp", withMessage message:String) {
        let alertController = UIAlertController (title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)

        let settingsAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .default) { (_) -> Void in
            guard let _ = URL(string: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString) else {
                return
            }

            self.navigate(To: UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString)

        }
        alertController.addAction(settingsAction)
        let cancelAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alertController.addAction(cancelAction)

        AppDelegate.sharedDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Hope it is helpful to you :)

Comment: Setting page am referring to is apple native setting apps not inside application.

Comment: @muthukumaresh BTW you are just checking the push permission is granted or not that can be done with provided code let me know if i am wrong

Comment: but we are not using @objc func switchChanged (sender:UISwitch) this function in any place.

Comment: @muthukumaresh Look I have put this code for your understanding purpose, You have First three blocks in answer  1) isPushEnabledFromSettings 2 ) isPushPermissionGiven method and 3)view did load method  that's it

Comment: cool and thank you. Am checking this in project. thanks for your help.