# How to detect OS user preference changes in a macOS app with Swift?

Tags: swift, macos

[image]

I'm building a macOS app that (among other things) sends notifications. In the app settings (right) I'm showing the current notification permission. If the access is not granted, I offer the option to open the system preferences. I want my app to reflect permission changes the user makes in the system preferences immediately to provide good feedback in the UI.

**Is there a way to be notified when the user performs changes to my apps notification permissions?**

I've done some research but [the solution I could find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51394245/how-to-listen-to-the-changes-in-notification-authorization-status) involves observing `NSApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification`, but that's not what I want. This way the app will only update once it gets activated again (when some action is performed) but I want to be notified immediately and using the `NSApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification` observer triggers every time the app becomes active, not just when settings change (leads to many unnecessary calls). Here's my code:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(checkNotificationStatus), name: NSApplication.didBecomeActiveNotification, object: nil)
```

I've also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50645149/update-uilabel-text-value-when-changing-the-user-permission-for-notification-i/50645392#50645392) but its basically using the same method.

*Does somebody have an idea how to accomplish that? I wish there was sth. like `NSApplication.didChangeSettingsNotification` :D*

Thank you in advance!